# SQL datetime format conversion

Tags: sql, postgresql

I should somehow convert data type to easily insert into table with datetime format.
From

```
2022-11-28T12:18:46.534919023Z
```

To
2022-11-28 12:18:46

BTW using PostgreSQL.
Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: What's your exact column type? Doesn't it work out of the box? https://dbfiddle.uk/Iep_ecb4

Comment: `datetime` is a binary value, it has no format. In most languages you can use parameterized queries so you *don't* have to convert anything to a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no conversion necessary. The indicated value `2022-11-28T12:18:46.534919023Z` can be directly inserted into a `timestamp with time zone (timestamptz)` column. See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/SJ5Pzw_N)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST( '2022-11-28T12:18:46.534919023Z' AS timestamp)
```

[image: Result]

More about **CAST** [PostgreSQL CAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createcast.html)